# Filter data by date?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've `column` that contains data like so,

```
07/2002
05/2005
04/2000

month/year
```

can I filter out data using query, i.e

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `fr` < '07/2002'
```

it should return `04/2000`

is't possible using `MySQL` or I've to use other language to select and filter out data like `PHP`?

Comment: Store the dates as dates (ymd) and the problem becomes trivial, and very fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**plan**

> - use [str_to_date](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-str_to_date-function.php)
>     to convert the start of month values to dates and compare

---

**query**

```
select *
from `table`
where str_to_date(concat('01/', fr), '%d/%m/%Y') 
      < 
      str_to_date('01/07/2002', '%d/%m/%Y')
;
```

**output**

```
+---------+
| fr      |
+---------+
| 04/2000 |
+---------+
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ec2cb/1)

---

**note**

while the above is a solution to the question as asked, it is just dealing with the symptoms not the underlying issue.

the real issue is the storage type being used to store date information
consider using actual dates to store this information. this causes the following symptoms :

**symptoms**

> - complexity : we have to perform further manipulations to transform into the date type we can use
> - performance ( see above )
> - maintenance ( [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32163576/filter-out-data-using-mysql-query/32163631) )

we can instead fix this issue where it is caused by changing the storage type to correctly reflect the semantic contents ( its date information and should be able to be compared in this way simply )

**fix**

```
alter table `table` add column fr_datetype date not null;

update `table`
set fr_datetype = str_to_date(concat('01/', fr), '%d/%m/%Y')
;

-- test conversion to date type
select 
'error converting' as test_conversion
from `table`
where concat(lpad(extract(month from fr_datetype), 2, '0'), '/', extract(year from fr_datetype)) <> fr
;

-- only finalise this based on successful completion of above select ( no rows returned )
alter table `table` drop column fr;
alter table `table` change column fr_datetype fr date not null;
```

**simplified solution**

```
select *
from `table`
where fr < '2002-07-01'
;
```

Comment: +1 mate, great, thank you very much.
but you didn't provide the link associated with "maintenance ( see this question )" lolx. Thank you.

Comment: i meant this exact question as an example of maintenance and complexity issues arising from imprecise data structure definitions

Comment: also, this will never go live, this application will only be used by one person, perhaps by 2, not more than 2. in that case, should I convert all data from `fr` to `fr_updated`?

Comment: i would still recommend doing so. particularly as you may find other needs to access and compare this field as a date

Comment: basically, I've two tables, one for actual data and other is exactly copy of the data(but with duplicates) so, it's better(I guess) to create trigger while inserting stuff into secondary table.

Comment: upto you, but you may want to also perform above date conversion on the archive table also - i sense another question ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use MySQL built in date format, so you can perform queries like this:

```
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date_field, '%m') < 7
AND DATE_FORMAT(date_field, '%y') < 2002
```

Or a simpler solution is to use timestamps (that stores seconds), and you can do things like:

```
WHERE timestamp_field < 1027407492
```

Or if you'd like to use dates as you're using it now (not recommended), store them in two columns. One for month and other one for year, then you can query like this:

```
WHERE month_field < 7
AND WHERE year_field < 2002
```

I recommend timestamps.